# Making Cocoa Application Scriptable Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, scripting, applescript

## Goal

I am trying to make my Cocoa Application that has been written in Swift scriptable from Applescript.

## What I've Done

I have created a SDEF file, configured my info.plist and created a class which I think is appropriate.

**definition.sdef**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">


<dictionary title="SamX">

    <!-- specific suite(s) for the application follow... -->
    <suite name="SamX Scripting Suite" code="Samx" description="Suite for communication with the application">

        <command name="savedoc" code="corecnte" description="description">
            <cocoa class="ProjectName.ScriptingSaveNotification" id="BLah"/>

            <parameter name="with dname" code="WTdc" type="text" optional="no" description="description">
                <cocoa key="DocumentName"/>
            </parameter>

            <result type="boolean" description="The result of the invocation. True if it succeeds, False if it does not"/>
        </command>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

**info.plist**

### [image: Info.plist]

**ScriptingSaveNotification.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class ScriptingSaveNotification: NSScriptCommand, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    override func performDefaultImplementation() -> AnyObject? {
        let parms = self.evaluatedArguments
        var name = ""
        if let args = parms {
            if let DocumentName = args["DocumentName"] as? String {
                name = DocumentName
            }
        }


        debugPrint("We were prompted to save");
        return "hello world"
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresentNotification notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        debugPrint("We were prompted to save");

        return true
    }
}
```

## Where I Am

I have an application that launches. The application's SDEF file appears to be reflecting in the Applescript Editor. The Applescript editors also returns a dictionary definition. However when I run the command, I always get an output of 5 (int), and none of my debug lines appears to be outputting in Xcode.

It appears to me that maybe I'm referencing my class in the SDEF improperly. But I'm not 100% sure. I've tried renaming it several times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Applescript Dictionary**
[image]

**Test Script**

```
tell application "MyApplication"
    set testString to "Hello"
    set returnValue to savedoc testString
    display alert returnValue
end tell
```

Comment: Just noticed that your script is wrong, too. You don't actually use the "with dname" parameter in your script. It should be: 

set returnValue to savedoc with dname testString

Comment: That was it. :facepalm. Thank you so much for the help. Feel free to edit your answer to also contain that answer, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

The main issue is that you don't actually use the `with dname` parameter in your script. It should be:

```
set returnValue to savedoc with dname testString
```

That said, the info below is still valid for creating a proper `sdef` and the other suggestions/examples may be helpful.

---

This is a basic example of passing a string in the `evaluatedArguments` of the `NSScriptCommand` and then returning that string as the result of the script command in Swift (you could return a boolean on success/failure of the command or any other type of result; and, actually, in your `sdef` you say you're going to return a `boolean` but your command is returning a `string` (`text` in `sdef` definitions)). Creating your `sdef` can be tricky. Your command's code should start with the suite's code and you can remove the `id` and `optional` parameter (if you omit the `optional` parameter, the default is that the parameter is required). If you do just need a single parameter you could also just use the `direct-parameter` instead.

You can download a demo project:

[ScriptableSwift.zip](http://www.jonn8.com/dist/ScriptableSwift.zip)

Here are the relevant bits (aside from the `plist` entries that you have correct in your tests).

**ScriptableSwift.sdef**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary title="ScriptableSwift Terminology">
    <suite name="ScriptableSwift Scripting Suite" code="SSss" description="Standard suite for application communication.">
        <command name="save" code="SSssSave" description="Save something.">
            <cocoa class="ScriptableSwift.SaveScriptCommand"/>
            <parameter name="in" code="Fpat" type="text" description="The file path in which to save the document.">
                <cocoa key="FilePath"/>
            </parameter>
            <result type="text" description="Echoes back the filepath supplied."/>
        </command>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

**SaveScriptCommand.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class SaveScriptCommand: NSScriptCommand {
    override func performDefaultImplementation() -> AnyObject? {
        let filePath = self.evaluatedArguments!["FilePath"] as! String
        debugPrint("We were prompted to save something at: \(filePath)");
        return filePath
    }
}
```

**Test AppleScript**

```
tell application "ScriptableSwift" to save in "path/to/file"
```

Result:

```
"path/to/file"
```

Comment: you sir are a hero and a scholar