# Why isn't making my Swift app scriptable working?

Tags: swift, macos, scriptable

I'm trying to make a Swift app, 'Earwig.app', MacOS, scriptable. I've started by shamelessly stealing an example from [Making Cocoa Application Scriptable Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194835/making-cocoa-application-scriptable-swift), adding two files, a .sdef and a .swift as listed below. I've set Scriptable and scripting definition filename in info.plist

My AppleScript is:

```
tell application "EarwigServer" to save in "path/to/file"
```

Running the script gives me an error, 'EarwigServer got an error: Can’t continue save.'

At this point I'm stuck. Any suggestions appreciated

sdef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">

<dictionary title="ScriptableSwift Terminology">

    <suite name="ScriptableSwift Scripting Suite" code="SSss" description="Standard suite for application communication.">

        <command name="save" code="SSssSave" description="Save something.">
            <cocoa class="ScriptableSwift.SaveScriptCommand"/>
            <parameter name="in" code="Fpat" type="text" description="The file path in which to save the document.">
                <cocoa key="FilePath"/>
            </parameter>
            <result type="text" description="Echoes back the filepath supplied."/>
        </command>

    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

swift file:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class SaveScriptCommand: NSScriptCommand {
    override func performDefaultImplementation() -> Any? {
        print( "in" )
        let filePath = self.evaluatedArguments!["FilePath"] as! String

        print( "here" )
        return filePath
    }
}
```

info.plist:

[image: info.plist]

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it couldn't work. The hassle is that any tiny mistake breaks the entire functionality. For example did you add the required keys and values in Info.plist?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've got info.plist right but I've edited the post with an added screengrab.

I've pretty much just added the two files from an example project that works with a view to adjusting them as needed. I wondered if I'd got the class name, ScriptableSwift.SaveScriptCommand, wrong. I've tried a number of permutations without luck.

Answer (score 1):

It started working when I changed `ScriptableSwift.SaveScriptCommand` to `EarwigServer.SaveScriptCommand`. Which seems obvious, I know but I'd done this before with no effect. It seems that changes don't take effect until I cleaned the build folder.

This xml works, the swift file remains unchanged:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">

<dictionary title="EarwigServer Terminology">

    <suite name="EarwigServer Scripting Suite" code="ESss" description="Standard suite for application communication.">

        <command name="run" code="ESssErun" description="Save something.">
            <cocoa class="EarwigServer.SaveScriptCommand"/>

            <parameter name="in" code="Fpat" type="text" description="The file path in which to save the document.">
                <cocoa key="FilePath"/>
            </parameter>
            <result type="text" description="Echoes back the filepath supplied."/>
        </command>

    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

Thanks for the input

Comment: Also, XML in the sdef file is very touchy about syntax while being very unhelpful about feeding back errors when scripts are run in the script editor. I'd introduced a tab before the XML tag on the first line and it took a while to track it down. Running a script in osascript reported the error in the file where running one in the script editor just returned an obscure error.

Comment: You helped me a lot